# Python for-loop stopping prematurely

Tags: python, range, bioinformatics

I'm trying to convert a DNA sequence to an amino acid sequence. I have a dictionary of codons:

```
codon_mapping = {'AAA': 'K','AAC': 'N','AAG': 'K','AAT': 'N','ACA': 'T','ACC': 'T','ACG': 'T','ACT': 'T','AGA': 'R','AGC': 'S','AGG': 'R','AGT': 'S','ATA': 'I','ATC': 'I','ATG': 'M','ATT': 'I','CAA': 'Q','CAC': 'H','CAG': 'Q','CAT': 'H','CCA': 'P','CCC': 'P','CCG': 'P','CCT': 'P','CGA': 'R','CGC': 'R','CGG': 'R','CGT': 'R','CTA': 'L','CTC': 'L','CTG': 'L','CTT': 'L','GAA': 'E','GAC': 'D','GAG': 'E','GAT': 'D','GCA': 'A','GCC': 'A','GCG': 'A','GCT': 'A','GGA': 'G','GGC': 'G','GGG': 'G','GGT': 'G','GTA': 'V','GTC': 'V','GTG': 'V','GTT': 'V','TAA': '*','TAC': 'Y','TAG': '*','TAT': 'Y','TCA': 'S','TCC': 'S','TCG': 'S','TCT': 'S','TGA': '*','TGC': 'C','TGG': 'W','TGT': 'C','TTA': 'L','TTC': 'F','TTG': 'L','TTT': 'F'}
```

And an input sequence:

```
seq = 'ATGTATGGCTAGCTTACTACTGCGCACTGATGTGGCTATCGATCGCTGGTCGTTGCTGACCGAGCTAAA'
```

I currently have this code:

```
#import re
import re

#find the start codons in the sequence
starts=[m.start() for m in re.finditer('ATG', seq)]

#establish new dictionary
seqDictionary={}
#translate sequences
for i in starts:
    mySeq=seq[i:]
    translated=''
    for n in range(0, len(mySeq), 3):
        print(mySeq[n:n+3])
        if codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]] != '*':
            translated += codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]]
        if codon_mapping[seq[n:n+3]] == '*':
            break 
    print("translated: " + translated)
    seqDictionary[i]=(translated)
print(seqDictionary)
            
AA_frame1 = seqDictionary[0] 
AA_frame2 = seqDictionary[4] 
AA_frame3 = seqDictionary[29]
AA_longest = None
```

the problem is that for the second and third sequences (from positions 4 and 29, respectively), the for-loop exits after the fourth amino acid, even though those are not stop codons.

The output of the above code is:

```
ATG
TAT
GGC
TAG
translated: MYG
ATG
GCT
AGC
TTA
translated: MASL
ATG
TGG
CTA
TCG
translated: MWLS
{0: 'MYG', 4: 'MASL', 29: 'MWLS'}
```

I'm not getting any error messages, and I can't figure out why the loop is exiting. I know the correct solutions for the translated sequences are:

```
MYG
MASLLLRTDVAIDRWSLLTEL
MWLSIAGRC
```

Edit, this final code worked:

```
#import re
import re

#find the start codons in the sequence
starts=[m.start() for m in re.finditer('ATG', seq)]

#establish new dictionary
seqDictionary={}
#translate sequences
for i in starts:
    mySeq=seq[i:]
    translated=''
    for n in range(0, len(mySeq), 3):
        if len(mySeq[n:n+3]) < 3:
            break
        if codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]] == '*':
            break
        else:
            translated += codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]]
    seqDictionary[i]=(translated)
print(seqDictionary)
```

Output:

```
{0: 'MYG', 4: 'MASLLLRTDVAIDRWSLLTEL', 29: 'MWLSIAGRC'}
```

Comment: is it because of a typo? `if codon_mapping[seq[n:n+3]] == '*':`, should the `seq` be `mySeq`?

Comment: I also suspect some confusions related to `seq` and `mySeq`. Why not `if codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]] != '*': #...; else: break` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]] != '*':
    translated += codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]]
if codon_mapping[seq[n:n+3]] == '*':
    break
```

here you are not checking the same thing. First if is checking `mySeq`, second if is checking `seq`.

this is better written as an if else than two ifs

```
if codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]] == '*':
    break
else:
    translated += codon_mapping[mySeq[n:n+3]]
```

Comment: if you do a break in `if` why have an `else:`

Comment: this is one if statement to achieve both outcomes, you have two if statements effectively checking the same thing. this way is neater. And if you'd done it this way, it wouldn't have been possible for you to make the mistake you did because you're not duplicating code.

Comment: @rioV8 sorry, you are not the OP, I read your question wrong! You're right, the else is not required. But for the example here it helps to highlight the way the if/else is taking the place of the two if's. There are lots of things in the OP's code I would improve myself if I was optimising.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the triplet is in the dictionary

```
for i in starts:
    mySeq=seq[i:]
    translated=''
    for n in range(0, len(mySeq), 3):
        subSeq = mySeq[n:n+3]
        print(subSeq)
        aAcid = codon_mapping.get(subSeq)
        if (not aAcid) or aAcid == '*': break
        translated += aAcid
    print("translated: " + translated)
    seqDictionary[i]=(translated)
```

---

With `itertools` the translation can be written in one line

```
import itertools
#establish new dictionary
seqDictionary={}
#translate sequences
for m in re.finditer('ATG', seq):
    start = m.start()
    translated =''.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda aa: aa and aa != '*', (codon_mapping.get(seq[n:n+3]) for n in range(start, len(seq), 3)) ))
    print("translated: " + translated)
    seqDictionary[start] = translated
print(seqDictionary)
```